# Getting the Nth column value of a selected range

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to do the following:

The user selects 2 ranges: e.g. 1st Range A1:A20, 2nd Range C1:E20
I'd like to append all values from the 2nd range into the 1st range.
However this part `v = v & .Areas(2).Columns(1).Value` results in a `Type Mismatch`

```
With Selection
    For i = 1 To .Areas(1).Count
        v = ""
        For j = 1 To .Areas(2).Columns.Count
            v = v & .Areas(2).Columns(1).Value
        Next j
        .Areas(1)(i).Value = v
    Next i
End With
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to address the cell on `aRow`, `aCol` from your `Range1`, you can use `Range1.Offset(aRow, aCol)`.

You can omit the row value, and just put the column reference, as `Range1.Offset(,aCol)`.

This is explained in [this URL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.offset).